# Throw ParentContainsErrorRecordException error in sh file in Intellij Idea in Windows

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

I have a problem about running the sh file shown below in Intellij Idea.

Here is the setup-aws.sh shown below.

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id "test"
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "test"
aws configure set default.region eu-west-3


aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 secretsmanager create-secret --name aws/secret --secret-string '{"my_uname":"username","my_pwd":"password"}'

aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566  s3api create-bucket \
              --bucket bucketname \
              --region eu-west-1 \
              --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-west-1
```

After configuring the run process of sh file in Intellij (Script path and Interpreter path) , I run the script but I got this issue shown below.

```
PS C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\library> "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\library\setup-aws.sh
At line:1 char:37                                                                                                           
+ ... es\Git\bin\bash.exe" C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\library\setup-aws.sh                                                 
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                    
Unexpected token 'C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\library\setup-aws.sh' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException          
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it help if you change Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Tools | Terminal | Shell path to bash.exe instead of using PowerShell?

Comment: I already did it but I got this issue.

Comment: Disable Run/Debug Configurations | Execute in the terminal option for Shell Script configuration.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have another issue regarding aws not running with localstack in docker-compose. Can you help me ? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363198/cannot-run-sh-file-regarding-aws-configure-in-localstack-in-docker-compose-yml

Answer (score 0):

I only run the script through this command shown below.

```
.\setup-aws.sh
```